# Sandbox Testing In App Purchase with Parse: kPFErrorPaymentDisabled

Tags: ios, parse-platform, in-app-purchase

I try to setup an In-App-Purchase (IAP) for my iOS App using the Parse SDK.

- I enabled IAP in the developer portal for my app.
- I enabled IAP in my XCode app project settings
- I created a consumable IAP in iTunes Connect. It says *waiting for screenshot* and *You do not currently have a iOS Paid Apps contract in effect.* However this should both not effect sandbox testing.
- I created a Sandbox account for IAP testing
- I logged out of my iTunes & Appstore account on my testing device. I did not login to the sandbox account in Settings

This is how I do the IAP in my code:

```
        PFPurchase.buyProduct("com.domain.MyIdentifier", block: { (error: NSError?) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
        })
```

I registered a handler in `AppDelegate`

```
    PFPurchase.addObserverForProduct("com.domain.MyIdentifier") { (transaction:SKPaymentTransaction) in
        print("purchased")
    }
```

It **does not prompt for login** where I want to put in my sandbox account credentials. I receive `kPFErrorPaymentDisabled` error from Parse.

What does that mean?

Comment: What does `SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs if IAP is disabled via `Restrictions` in Settings.